# 404 error on redirect using URL Rewrite

Tags: redirect, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I'm using the following rule in web.config to redirect from `xpda.com/bugpage` to `xpda.com/bugs`. I need subfolders and URL parameters to be passed along, and it does this correctly.

Now I would like to remove the folder `bugpage`, but when I do this the server shows a 404 error whenever I use the URL `xpda.com/bugpage`. An empty folder named `bugpage` will prevent this error.

Is there another rule form I can use, or maybe an IIS setting, to prevent the 404 error? (I need subfolders and parameters to be carried along into the new URL.)

```
<rule name="bugpage" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/bugpage(.+)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/bugs{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the add input line to this:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/bugpage(.*)" />
```

Also, make sure any applications are deleted along with with their associated folders, to prevent a 500 error.